# How to check and uncheck a custom react js checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a custom react checkbox, and am making an API call from the backend server. After mapping through the array of data I want to do a check if the item.name in each mapped object is equal to the value of appkeys.appName, then let the checkbox be checked, else it shouldn't. Also, I want to be able to check the ones that are not checked and also be able to uncheck the ones that are checked already when the comparison returns true.

Here is the full code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card from "../Card";
import cn from "classnames";
import toaster from "../../utils/toaster";
import { makeApiCall } from "../../lib/api";
// import Filters from "../../screens/RolesDash/Filters";
import styles from "../../screens/ProductsDashboard/ProductsDashboard.module.sass";
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";

function SingleAppService({ appID, appkeys }) {
  //   console.log(appkeys, "Keys");
  const [appServices, setAppServices] = useState([{ appName: "aaa" }]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  // const [checkedServices, setCheckedServices] = useState(false);
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({}); // State to keep track of checked checkboxes

  const getStatisticsGraph = async () => {
    // e.preventDefault()
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await makeApiCall(`/app-roles?searchParam=${appID}`);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setAppServices(response?.data);
      //   setSelectedFilters(response?.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      toaster("Something Went Wrong", "error");
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getStatisticsGraph();
    console.log(appkeys);
  }, []);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (serviceId) => {
    setCheckedItems((prevState) => {
      const updatedCheckedItems = { ...prevState };

      if (
        appServices.filter(
          (item) => console.log(item, "This is items")
          // item.serviceId === serviceId && item.name === appkeys.appName
        )
      ) {
        // If it initially matched the condition, uncheck it
        updatedCheckedItems[serviceId] = false;
      } else {
        // Otherwise, toggle the checkbox state
        updatedCheckedItems[serviceId] = !prevState[serviceId];
      }

      return updatedCheckedItems;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <Card title="App Services" classTitle={cn("title-green")}>
        <div className="services-keys">
          {appServices?.map((appService, index) => {
            return (
              <Checkbox
                className={styles.checkbox}
                content={appService}
                value={
                  appService.appName === appkeys.appName
                    ? true
                    : checkedItems[appService.serviceId] || false
                }
                onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(appService.serviceId)}
                key={index}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <button
          className={cn("button-small", styles.button)}
          style={{ width: "20rem ", textAlign: "center", marginTop: "1rem" }}
          // onClick={handleWebHookSubmit}
        >
          {/* {saving ? "Saving..." : "Save"} */}
          Assign Services
        </button>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SingleAppService;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.